# Calculate returns and insert into another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table MF_NAVs which holds daily NAVs of mutual funds. I want to calculate the absolute returns over 1 day, 7 day, 15 days, 1 month, 3 month, 6 month, 1 year, 3 year, 5 year & since inception. And then INSERT the calculated values into another table MF_Returns.

The table structure and sample data for MF_NAVs is given below. I have also created a fiddle at the following link : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fYam96yYZo5tQLGLtcbhaQ/1

I use the SELECT query given below to calculate the absolute returns. The result from this query is also given below. My problem is I'm unable to save the result of this query into the MF_RETURNS table [structure given below].

The MF_NAVs table has around 20k different SchemeCode. Each SchemeCode has NAVs for different periods ranging from past few days to several months.

Please help save the calculated returns into MF_Returns table.

**Query to calculate returns:**

```
SELECT SchemeCode,Date,NetAssetValue, 
    ROUND((((L.LatestNAV)-NetAssetValue)/NetAssetValue)*100,2) AS AbsoluteReturns
FROM MF_NAVs 
JOIN (SELECT NetAssetValue AS LatestNAV FROM MF_NAVs WHERE SchemeCode=120503 ORDER BY DATE DESC LIMIT 1) AS L
WHERE SchemeCode=120503 
AND FIND_IN_SET(
      Date, 
      (
SELECT 
         CONCAT_WS( ',',
           Y.MaxDate, #LatestDate - MaxDate
           DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-01-01'), #YTD - Year To Datw
           MAX(CASE WHEN `Date` <= Y.MaxDate - INTERVAL 1 DAY THEN Date END), #1Day
           MAX(CASE WHEN `Date` <= Y.MaxDate - INTERVAL 7 DAY THEN Date END), #7Day
           MAX(CASE WHEN `Date` <= Y.MaxDate - INTERVAL 15 DAY THEN Date END), #15Day
           MAX(CASE WHEN `Date` <= Y.MaxDate - INTERVAL 1 MONTH THEN Date END), #1Month
           MAX(CASE WHEN `Date` <= Y.MaxDate - INTERVAL 3 MONTH THEN Date END), #3Month
           MAX(CASE WHEN `Date` <= Y.MaxDate - INTERVAL 6 MONTH THEN Date END), #6Month
           MAX(CASE WHEN `Date` <= Y.MaxDate - INTERVAL 1 YEAR THEN Date END), #1Year
           MAX(CASE WHEN `Date` <= Y.MaxDate - INTERVAL 3 YEAR THEN Date END), #3Year
           MAX(CASE WHEN `Date` <= Y.MaxDate - INTERVAL 5 YEAR THEN Date END), #5Year
           MIN(Date) #Inception
         )
       FROM MF_NAVs
       JOIN (SELECT MAX(Date) AS MaxDate FROM MF_NAVs WHERE SchemeCode=120503) AS Y
       WHERE SchemeCode=120503
          ) 
    )
ORDER BY Date DESC
```

**Table Structure : MF_NAVs**

```
CREATE TABLE `MF_NAVs` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `SchemeCode` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Date` date NOT NULL,
  `NetAssetValue` decimal(15,5) NOT NULL
)
```

**Sample Data: MF_NAVs**

```
+------------+------------+---------------+
| SchemeCode | Date       | NetAssetValue |
+------------+------------+---------------+
| 120503     | 2021-04-13 | 65.59480      |
+------------+------------+---------------+
| 120503     | 2021-04-12 | 65.22200      |
+------------+------------+---------------+
| 120503     | 2021-04-09 | 67.70330      |
+------------+------------+---------------+
| 120503     | 2021-04-08 | 67.89580      |
+------------+------------+---------------+
| 120503     | 2021-04-06 | 66.39850      |
+------------+------------+---------------+
| 120503     | 2021-04-05 | 66.11320      |
+------------+------------+---------------+
| 120503     | 2021-04-01 | 67.03710      |
+------------+------------+---------------+
| 120503     | 2021-03-26 | 65.79040      |
+------------+------------+---------------+
| 120503     | 2021-03-25 | 64.86400      |
+------------+------------+---------------+
| 120503     | 2021-03-12 | 68.38530      |
+------------+------------+---------------+
| 120503     | 2021-03-09 | 68.54100      |
+------------+------------+---------------+
| 120503     | 2021-01-13 | 66.05340      |
+------------+------------+---------------+
| 120503     | 2021-01-12 | 66.90930      |
+------------+------------+---------------+
| 120503     | 2021-01-08 | 66.77000      |
+------------+------------+---------------+
| 120503     | 2021-01-01 | 64.98200      |
+------------+------------+---------------+
| 120503     | 2020-10-13 | 51.78950      |
+------------+------------+---------------+
| 120503     | 2020-10-12 | 52.00310      |
+------------+------------+---------------+
| 120503     | 2020-10-09 | 52.06840      |
+------------+------------+---------------+
| 120503     | 2013-01-02 | 15.02530      |
+------------+------------+---------------+
| 120503     | 2016-04-08 | 29.94380      |
+------------+------------+---------------+
| 120503     | 2016-04-12 | 30.46710      |
+------------+------------+---------------+
| 120503     | 2016-04-13 | 30.94700      |
+------------+------------+---------------+
| 120503     | 2018-04-09 | 44.67440      |
+------------+------------+---------------+
| 120503     | 2018-04-12 | 45.10190      |
+------------+------------+---------------+
| 120503     | 2018-04-13 | 45.18520      |
+------------+------------+---------------+
| 120503     | 2020-04-09 | 43.82900      |
+------------+------------+---------------+
| 120503     | 2020-04-13 | 42.89580      |
+------------+------------+---------------+
```

**Table Structure : MF_RETURNS**

```
CREATE TABLE MF_RETURNS (
    `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `SchemeCode` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `LatestDate` date NOT NULL,
    `YTDDate` date NOT NULL,
    `YTDAbsoluteReturns` decimal(15,5) NOT NULL,
    `1DayDate` date NOT NULL,
    `1DayAbsoluteReturns` decimal(15,5) NOT NULL, 
    `7DayDate` date NOT NULL,
    `7DayAbsoluteReturns` decimal(15,5) NOT NULL,
    `15DayDate` date NOT NULL,
    `15DayAbsoluteReturns` decimal(15,5) NOT NULL, 
    `1MonthDate` date NOT NULL,
    `1MonthAbsoluteReturns` decimal(15,5) NOT NULL, 
    `3MonthDate` date NOT NULL,
    `3MonthAbsoluteReturns` decimal(15,5) NOT NULL, 
    `6MonthDate` date NOT NULL,
    `6MonthAbsoluteReturns` decimal(15,5) NOT NULL, 
    `1YearDate` date NOT NULL,
    `1YearAbsoluteReturns` decimal(15,5) NOT NULL,
    `3YearDate` date NOT NULL,
    `3YearAbsoluteReturns` decimal(15,5) NOT NULL,
    `5YearDate` date NOT NULL,
    `5YearAbsoluteReturns` decimal(15,5) NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**Query Output**

```
+------------+------------+---------------+-----------------+
| SchemeCode | Date       | NetAssetValue | AbsoluteReturns |
+------------+------------+---------------+-----------------+
| 120503     | 2021-04-13 | 65.59480      | 0.00            |
+------------+------------+---------------+-----------------+
| 120503     | 2021-04-12 | 65.22200      | 0.57            |
+------------+------------+---------------+-----------------+
| 120503     | 2021-04-06 | 66.39850      | -1.21           |
+------------+------------+---------------+-----------------+
| 120503     | 2021-03-26 | 65.79040      | -0.30           |
+------------+------------+---------------+-----------------+
| 120503     | 2021-03-12 | 68.38530      | -4.08           |
+------------+------------+---------------+-----------------+
| 120503     | 2021-01-13 | 66.05340      | -0.69           |
+------------+------------+---------------+-----------------+
| 120503     | 2021-01-01 | 64.98200      | 0.94            |
+------------+------------+---------------+-----------------+
| 120503     | 2020-10-13 | 51.78950      | 26.66           |
+------------+------------+---------------+-----------------+
| 120503     | 2020-04-13 | 42.89580      | 52.92           |
+------------+------------+---------------+-----------------+
| 120503     | 2018-04-13 | 45.18520      | 45.17           |
+------------+------------+---------------+-----------------+
| 120503     | 2016-04-13 | 30.94700      | 111.96          |
+------------+------------+---------------+-----------------+
| 120503     | 2013-01-02 | 15.02530      | 336.56          |
+------------+------------+---------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: which MySQL version you are using and do you want to store the results only for one schemacode with this query or direct for all ?

Comment: MySQL version 10.3.27. I want to trigger and store the result of individual schemecode whenever a new NAV is inserted in MF_NAVs. One new record is inserted in MF_NAVs every night for almost every schemecode.

Comment: so, it MariaDB not MySQL. Did you want to insert (first time) and then update the ROW in the result table or add every time ?

Comment: 1. Correct MariaDB. 2. Update row result table.

Comment: @BerndBuffen Is it something doable from within the database? Thanks for you help, I appreciate your time.

Comment: Yes, you can do with the Database. I have a little problem to assign the correct values to the row. You return 12 Rows and only 10 in the return table. I will post now a SAMPLE, not the correct complited answer.

Comment: where are you from. can we have a telefone call the clear some things

Comment: I'm from India. ATM wont be possible to talk. I had missed 2 fields in MF_Returns table. The 2 rows shoudl have been     `InceptionDate` date NOT NULL, & 
    `InceptionReturns` decimal(15,5) NOT NULL

Comment: i not understand what you mean with **ATM wont be possible to talk**. i think i have not all information to finish the query. only some hints for you. create indexe, one unique key  on schemecode in the resulttable and store it with **insert into ... on duplicate kay ....**

Comment: Ohh I'm sorry. What I meant was 'At the moment' (ATM) I wont be able to talk on phone because it is 3:30 AM in India. I'm really sorry I did not mean to rub you the wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ONLY TEMP SAMPLE. I will correct it after some questions are cleared.

```
SELECT
    null as ID,
    SchemeCode
    
    , MAX( IF(id=3, r.`Date`,null) ) AS 1DayDate
    , MAX( IF(id=3, r.`AbsoluteReturns`,null) ) AS 1DayAbsoluteReturns
    
    , MAX( IF(id=4, r.`Date`,null) ) AS 7DayDate
    , MAX( IF(id=4, r.`AbsoluteReturns`,null) ) AS 7DayAbsoluteReturns
    
    , MAX( IF(id=5, r.`Date`,null) ) AS 15DayDate
    , MAX( IF(id=5, r.`AbsoluteReturns`,null) ) AS 15DayAbsoluteReturns
    
    , MAX( IF(id=6, r.`Date`,null) ) AS 1MonthDate
    , MAX( IF(id=6, r.`AbsoluteReturns`,null) ) AS 1MonthAbsoluteReturns
    
    , MAX( IF(id=7, r.`Date`,null) ) AS 3MonthDate
    , MAX( IF(id=7, r.`AbsoluteReturns`,null) ) AS 3MonthAbsoluteReturns
    
    , MAX( IF(id=9, r.`Date`,null) ) AS 6MonthDate
    , MAX( IF(id=8, r.`AbsoluteReturns`,null) ) AS 6MonthAbsoluteReturns
    
    , MAX( IF(id=10, r.`Date`,null) ) AS 1YearDate
    , MAX( IF(id=10, r.`AbsoluteReturns`,null) ) AS 1YearAbsoluteReturns
    
    , MAX( IF(id=11, r.`Date`,null) ) AS 3YearDate
    , MAX( IF(id=11, r.`AbsoluteReturns`,null) ) AS 3YearAbsoluteReturns
    
    , MAX( IF(id=12, r.`Date`,null) ) AS 5YearDate
    , MAX( IF(id=12, r.`AbsoluteReturns`,null) ) AS 5YearAbsoluteReturns
    
FROM (

SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY `SchemeCode` order by `Date` desc ) AS id,  
    SchemeCode,Date,NetAssetValue,
    ROUND((((L.LatestNAV)-NetAssetValue)/NetAssetValue)*100,2) AS AbsoluteReturns
FROM MF_NAVs 
JOIN (SELECT NetAssetValue AS LatestNAV FROM MF_NAVs WHERE SchemeCode=120503 ORDER BY DATE DESC LIMIT 1) AS L
WHERE SchemeCode=120503 
AND FIND_IN_SET(
      Date, 
      (
SELECT 
         CONCAT_WS( ',',
           Y.MaxDate, #LatestDate - MaxDate
           DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-01-01'), #YTD - Year To Datw
           MAX(CASE WHEN `Date` <= Y.MaxDate - INTERVAL 1 DAY THEN Date END), #1Day
           MAX(CASE WHEN `Date` <= Y.MaxDate - INTERVAL 7 DAY THEN Date END), #7Day
           MAX(CASE WHEN `Date` <= Y.MaxDate - INTERVAL 15 DAY THEN Date END), #15Day
           MAX(CASE WHEN `Date` <= Y.MaxDate - INTERVAL 1 MONTH THEN Date END), #1Month
           MAX(CASE WHEN `Date` <= Y.MaxDate - INTERVAL 3 MONTH THEN Date END), #3Month
           MAX(CASE WHEN `Date` <= Y.MaxDate - INTERVAL 6 MONTH THEN Date END), #6Month
           MAX(CASE WHEN `Date` <= Y.MaxDate - INTERVAL 1 YEAR THEN Date END), #1Year
           MAX(CASE WHEN `Date` <= Y.MaxDate - INTERVAL 3 YEAR THEN Date END), #3Year
           MAX(CASE WHEN `Date` <= Y.MaxDate - INTERVAL 5 YEAR THEN Date END), #5Year
           MIN(Date) #Inception
         )
       FROM MF_NAVs
       JOIN (SELECT MAX(Date) AS MaxDate FROM MF_NAVs WHERE SchemeCode=120503) AS Y
       WHERE SchemeCode=120503
          ) 
    )
ORDER BY Date DESC 

) r
GROUP BY r.SchemeCode;
```

Comment: Thank you @Brend Buffen. Your answer and comment above helped me immensely.